# How to create a running 3 observation average in SAS?

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I have a dataset with some volumes in a column and I want to create a second column that contains the average of the previous three observations.  Is this possible?

e.g.

```
data have;

  input Vol  Avg_pre_4;
  datalines;

  228  . 
  141  .
  125  .
  101  164.66
  116  122.33
  107  114
  74   108
  118  99
  127  99.67
  123  106.33
  ;
run;
```

Comment: Check if you have SAS ETS licensed.  If so then `proc expand` has inbuilt functionality to perform moving averages

Comment: Yes that works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `LAG` function is an automatic built-in queue.

```
VOL_AVG_OF_PRIOR3 = MEAN ( lag(Vol), lag2(Vol), lag3(Vol) )
if _n_ < 4 then VOL_AVG_OF_PRIOR3 = .;
```